# Getting sum of values of a specific customer from Sqlite Table using c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am working on a C# application using Sqlite for database and storing some values of different customers.
I want to get sum of values of a column for a specific customer. I don't want to update existing values as I want them to stored right there in case I need them in future. 
I just want to get all values summed up and I want to perform some calculation on that sum and then store it as totalAmount in same table.

This picture might give you a better understanding. ASHRAF is customer and it has position1 and position2 columns. Position1 column sum would be -4000 and Position2 column sum would be 30000. I want that -4000 and 30000 return as a result of my query. How can I achieve that?

[image: Need to get sum of that position1 and position2 column of this specific customer ASHRAF]

Comment: `I just want to get all values summed up and I want to perform some calculation on that sum and then store it as totalAmount in same table` please show what you have so we can help you figure the problem out. We will be glad to help once we know what you have tried first.

Comment: Show us your code so we can help you. For example, are you using Entity Framework / Entity Framework Core? This would make things simpler for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SQL` you would do this

```
select SUM(position1) as POSITION1SUM, SUM(position2) as POSITION2SUM FROM 
clientPosition WHERE name = 'ASHRAF'
```

In `LINQ` you would say `TableName(Or the ListObject).Sum(x=>x.Position1)`

Update: SQL query to get values

```
DECLARE @SUM1 INT
DECLARE @SUM2 INT
select @SUM1 = SUM(Col1), @SUM2 = SUM(Col2) from TableName
```

Update2: IF you are using ADO.Net, use ExecuteReader and you do not need the SQL variables in that case, just a simple `select SUM(Col1) as Sum1, SUM(Col2) as Sum2 from TableName`.
[ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8) only returns a single value and so would be inappropriate in this case, please spend sometime reading about the most common data interaction functions.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate like what this query will return and what do I need to use to get both sums in a variable? Do I need to use SqliteCommand.ExecuteScalar method or ExecuteReader?

Comment: Are you asking about the SQL query?

Comment: Yes Rakesh. I want to get those "POSITION1SUM" and "POSITION2SUM" in string. I know ExecuteScalar is inappropriate in this case. Do I need to use ExecuteReader or what? And plz share some good tutorial material to learn about data interation functions. Thanks

Comment: Yes, ExecuteReader and use the SQL query from Update 2.

Comment: Microsoft is a great place to start - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8